# Image Compression Using MagickQuick in AEM

Tags: java, aem, processbuilder, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageQuick Tool to compress the DAM images. I am using below snippet for conversion.

```
try {
            System.out.println(" Image is Processing :: " + assetDetails.getName() + "Original Size :: " + assetDetails.getSize());
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16\\convert.exe", "-quality", "85%", assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath(), assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath());
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println(p.waitFor());
            session.save();

        } catch (final IOException | RepositoryException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting an error as below :

```
 Image is Processing :: A.jpgOriginal Size :: 323.8 KB
convert.exe: unable to open image `/content/dam/A.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2761.
convert.exe: no images defined `/content/dam/A.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Here code is looking for the file from /content/dam from local. How can I do this operation on existing images.

In case, I add the server name before path, I am getting below error :

```
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: no data returned `http://localhost:4502/content/dam/A.jpg' @ error/url.c/ReadURLImage/247.
convert.exe: no images defined `http://localhost:4502/content/dam/A.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

PFA* [image]

Comment: Why did you tag it with [tag:aem]? Seems to be unrelated, look at the tag description

Comment: Actually, Assets are hosted on AEM server.

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong path (a linux path, not a windows path), make sure you use the right path.

Answer (score 1):

The path `/content/dam/A.jpg` is relative to the JCR repository, not to the actual file system, so an image not found exception is launched. 
Also the hardcoded value of your ImageMagick installation path, `"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16\\convert.exe` doesn't seem too flexible IMHO, as it will be probably different in other environments (test, pre-prod, prod, ...).

Actually, if you want to use IM to improve image compression, I would recommend you to add custom Process Steps to the `DAM Update Asset` workflow.

For example, for creating a fixed 1140x1140 PNG compressed rendition I would use:

```
<node1
        jcr:primaryType="cq:WorkflowNode"
        description="This process step uses IM PNG compression."
        title="IM PNG Mime Type"
        type="PROCESS">
        <metaData
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            COMMANDS="convert ${directory}/${filename} -resize 1140x1140> -strip -depth 24 -define png:compression-filter=2 -define png:compression-level=9 -define png:compression-strategy=1 cq5dam.web.1140.1140.${extension}"
            MIME_TYPES="image/png"
            PROCESS="com.day.cq.dam.core.process.CommandLineProcess"
            PROCESS_AUTO_ADVANCE="true"/>
</node1>
```

You can read more about the command in the [IM doc](http://imagemagick.org/script/) and if you are interesting on integrating this in the OOTB AEM workflow, take the node model content from above as an example or take a look at this pretty well described [AEM Assets - best practices](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/assets/using/best-practices-for-imagemagick.html) article.

Comment: i support the recommendation to use the DAM Update Asset workflow for compression.

Comment: I have checked this earlier. Let say we have already GBs of image files in DAM. In case If I update workflow, how can i achieve the image compression on existing files?

Comment: Create a java process to query the assets uploaded before a certain date (e.g today) and rerun the DAM Update Asset workflow on them.

Comment: I tried the same, added command to compress the jpeg image. PFA*. I am getting an error : 23.04.2018 17:06:23.951 *ERROR* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/server0/2018-04-23_2/update_asset_4:/content/dam/Image-Quality.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/original] com.day.cq.dam.core.process.CommandLineProcess execute: failed to execute command [convert -define jpeg:size=319x319 Image-Quality.jpg -thumbnail 319x319 cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png] for asset [/content/dam/Image-Quality.jpg]: 
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 4(Exit value: 4)

Comment: That's caused by your OS. The convert command may not run with certain Windows versions (for example Windows SE), because it conflicts with the native convert utility that is part of Windows installation. Replace 'convert' with the complete path of the ImageMagick utility: e.g "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16\convert.exe". Does it work?